# Undefined 'not' command visual studio c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, command

There is a command typed not that does the same thing as `!=` as a not equal to comparative in C++. I saw this in a book called 'Exploring C++ the programmers introduction', as follows:

```
if(not x) {
   ...
}
```

I have replaced this `not` with `!` and the code compiles, but since the book has used it over a dozen times surely there is something I'm missing. Obviously, I can define it globally or just write `!` instead, but I want to know which library that command is stored.

Comment: It certainly is defined as an *alternative token* in C++, equivalent to `!` (not to `!=`, which can be written `not_eq`). But it sounds like this might be yet another area where that compiler makes up its own rules.

Comment: @MikeSeymour is correct. However, why do you even _want_ to use **not** instead of the more commonplace syntax if it adds unnecessary ambiguity during compilation? This is both a question to the OP and to anyone else with knowledge on the subject.

Comment: AlexD answered the question. @Mike Seymour the `!` and `!=0` are interchangeable. I think these _alternative tokens_ are designed for readability, which C# has expanded on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to use `not`, `and`, etc. (not sure if it is a good idea or not), and you have `VC++`, try to add this header

```
#include <iso646.h>
```

or

```
#include <ciso646>
```

See [C alternative tokens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_alternative_tokens):

> The above mentioned identifiers are operator keywords in the ISO C++ programming language and do not require the inclusion of a header file. For consistency, the C++98 standard provides the header `<ciso646>`. However the latter file has no effect, being empty. Notwithstanding some compilers, such as Microsoft Visual C++, do require the header to be included in order to use these identifiers.

Comment: I am using MS Visual Studio 2013 and this only compiled with those two headers you mentioned.

Comment: @GavinHull Correct. VS 2013 uses VC++ (Microsoft Visual C++), which does require one of the headers.